# Hololens won't start the app if I put a c#script in its content (il2cpp)

Tags: hololens

I'm a new hololensdeveloper and I recently made a Hololensproject using net scripting backend just because there were way more information on how to set it up and get it working with Visual Studio.

Now when I feel somewhat confident I decided to change it up to il2cpp, but I have a major issue.

Everytime I put a c#script(even empty ones) into any folder within the application the Hololens won't even start it. The screen goes black for some seconds and then returns me to the mainpage.

This feels strange as all the scripts from the HolotoolKit works fine and they are written with c#.

Im currently using
  .Unity 2018.3.4f1
  .HolotoolKit 2017
  .Visual Studio 2017

Thank you!

-----Solved------
SO after alot of time, I switched to Unity LTS and that fixed my problem. Feels bad that I have to rely on an older version.

Comment: Can you run the app in the editor?

Comment: @slaphshot33324 Yes. I can run it anywhere except in the Hololens.

Comment: After switching to IL2CPP did you completely delete everything from the folder that you build to in Unity so that no code is left over from the .NET scripting backend build?

Comment: @slaphshot33324 The project is entirely new. All I did was add the holotoolkit, set it up and build it. If I then add any c#script anywhere (usually in my own script folder), rebuild it. Then it wont start anymore.

If I then remove the script, rebuild it, the project will launch once again.

Comment: Can you put your entire solution on a different computer and see if you can build and run it there?  Just wondering if it is environmental.  Also, are you using a real Hololens or the emulator?

Comment: Sorry I don't have another computer available, and yes, it's on a real hololens.

Comment: What happens when you run your application with Visual Studio attached? Do you get any errors in the log files? Does it crash or does it just exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, using the HoloToolKit and not the mrtk v1 or v2, you should use [Unity LTS 2017](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases). Maybe thats the problem?

And I'm not sure if I understood you the right way. So you are building it in unity and than deploying it to the HoloLens without getting any errors in your console?
Also changing the scripting backend framework, means using a different build directory and If you are not doing that Unity should give you a message like "Build path contains project built with IL2CPP or .Net"

Comment: Yes, It builds without any problem and as usual you can play it in unitys gamewindow. But once I open it inside the Hololens it wont start unless it's clear of c#scripts (other than the imported ones from the toolkit). 

I guess i'll give the LTS a try but it feels strange that using .net scripting backend works flawlessly.

Comment: ouh wait, I guess I know what happens. You are just building the project normally, open it with visual studio, make some changes and then deploy, right? If yes,then you have to check "Unity C# Projects" in your build window.
But otherwise you wont open the project the other way to make some changes, because the hierarchy of the project would look strange in vs and you would not like to make some changes :/...

Comment: how/where are you adding scripts? Are you adding them after the project was build?

Comment: The project is entirely new. All I did was add the holotoolkit, set it up and build it. If I then add any c#script anywhere (usually in my own script folder), rebuild it. Then it wont start anymore. If I then remove the script, rebuild it, the project will launch once again. I never add/remove anything without rebuilding the project.

Comment: Yeah, but did you add the script in unity and then build it or are you adding it in the already builded project via visual studio? Dont know if this even matters, but sometimes unity does not like it, when somebody is doing stuff outside unity...

Comment: I rightclicked in unity and pressed "add c# script" (made it empty or put some code in, doesnt matter), rebuilded and opened the sln file with VS.

Comment: never heards sth like that, very strange! Did you fix the problem?

Comment: No I did not. Actually did build several more projects and all of them had the same result. What I noticed is if your script has a namespace in it (not legit script) you can play it in the hololens, but real working scripts does not.  And when you have IL2CPP has scripting backend you cant click on  "Unity C# Projects" as it's greyed out.